# Display Serial port data on web page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to display continuous stream of data from a serial port (COM4) on a web page. I tried to use NodeJS and successfully got my output on Command Prompt. But I am unable to figure out how to display it on a web page on localhost. Here is a piece of code I have got with me for displaying it on console.

```
var sys = require("sys"),
serialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;

// Create new serialport pointer
var serial = new serialPort("COM4" , { baudrate : 9600 });

// Add data read event listener
serial.on( "data", function( chunk ) {
    sys.puts(chunk);
});
serial.on( "error", function( msg ) {
    sys.puts("error: " + msg );
});
```

Please help me with the further steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use websocket or socket.js to listen and emit your streaming data and rendering it to client.